# How to update column of duplicate row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table `tUser` with columns `username`, `password`, `email`, `Active`.

I need to set the `Active` column of duplicate rows to 0. How can I achieve this?

Eg: Table values are

```
UserName    Password   Email             Active
-----------------------------------------------
Demo        demo       abc@gmail.com       1
Demo        demo       abc@gmail.com       1
Demo        demo       abc@gmail.com       1
```

I need to change this value to

```
Demo demo abc@gmail.com 1
```

and the other 2 rows should be

```
Demo demo abc@gmail.com 0
Demo demo abc@gmail.com 0
```

Comment: What defines a *duplicate* ? Same username? Or same username + same e-mail? Also: what uniquely identifies each row (e.g. what is the **primary key** of your table)?

Comment: @marc_s... Yes, username,email.Active columns form duplicate. we have a primary key UserID in the table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have a **primary key** in your table that uniquely identifies **each row**, then you can use a CTE and this approach to weed out any duplicates:

```
;WITH Duplicates AS
(
    SELECT
        UserID, Username, Password, Email, Active,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Username, Email ORDER BY UserID)
    FROM
        tUser
)
UPDATE tUser
SET Active = 0
FROM Duplicates d
WHERE d.UserID = tUser.UserID
  AND d.RowNum > 1
```

Comment: is this condition `WHERE d.UserID = tUser.UserID` really needed here?

Comment: @John Yes. Otherwise all data in tUser will have `Active = 0`